# How to stop Vim from splitting window horizontally when doing an :Ex

Tags: vim

When I use :Ex to open a new file, Vim sometimes decides to split the window horizontally. I don't like that behavior. I prefer what Vim usually does, which is to open the file in its own... window, I guess it's called in Vim? Anyway, when it doesn't split the window horizontally. How can I control what behavior is trigger by an :Ex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `:h` is your friend. `:h :Ex` shows you the following:

> :Explore  will open the local-directory browser on the current file's
> directory (or on directory [dir] if specified).  The window will be       split only if the file has been modified and |'hidden'| is
> not set,    otherwise the browsing window will take over that window.
> Normally    the splitting is taken horizontally.    Also see:
> |netrw-:Rexplore|

So vim will split the window, if you haven't saved your changes. This is to ensure, that you don't lose anything. I am not aware of any possibility to turn it off. You could of course redefine `:Ex` to just discard or save changes.

Comment: So I've been using Vim for a few years and did not know about that context-senstive help option. Thank you.